# Convert dictionary with sub-list of dictionaries into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this code with a dictionary "dict":

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {
    '2000': [{'team': 'Manchester United', 'points': '91'}],
    '2001': [{'team': 'Manchester United', 'points': '80'}],
    '2002': [{'team': 'Arsenal', 'points': '87'}]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index')
print(df)
```

The result is:

```
                                                 0
2000  {'team': 'Manchester United', 'points': '91'}
2001  {'team': 'Manchester United', 'points': '80'}
2002            {'team': 'Arsenal', 'points': '87'}
```

But what I want is:

```
        team                  points
2000    Manchester United     91
2001    Manchester United     80
2002    Arsenal               87
```

I would like to obtain this, without using loops in python, and by using pandas.
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df = df[0].apply(pd.Series)` ?

Comment: Thats exactly it!! Thanks Henry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tr this. This would depend on how large your data is.

```
diction =  {
    '2000': [{'team': 'Manchester United', 'points': '91'}],
    '2001': [{'team': 'Manchester United', 'points': '80'}],
    '2002': [{'team': 'Arsenal', 'points': '87'}]
}
transformed_dict= {x:d for x,y in diction.items() for d in y }
df = pd.DataFrame(transformed_dict)
df.T
```

Comment: Thanks Ade, but this would still involve python loops… Not as efficient as a dataframe/numpy function. Henry’s solution is the best approach:

df = df[0].apply(pd.Series)

Comment: I agree, the best bet is store it as a dictionary rather than a list(dict))